# Changing color of a portion in picture

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am doing such type of project, in my project,  i want to change the color of only  a portion of  my picture, for example when I click on a button I want the blue become green,  i want to know if there is any way to do that or it's impossible 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPhur.png]

Comment: HI @issam, please add more information about what you are trying to do and what you have tried - people need context and code to be able to help you out - as is, there's a million ways to interpret the question.

Comment: You could define two images of the button and call the "green" image onClick. There are a lot of ways to achieve it.

Comment: i'd like to know if there is other way than using two images because this gonna need 100 images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the above feature, you could define a shape and place it above the button and then change the color onClick. A simple example is:

shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:topRightRadius="4dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp">
</corners>
<solid
android:color="#4848ea">
</solid>
</shape>
```

Now change the color of the shape using the following code.

```
GradientDrawable Shape = (GradientDrawable)shape.getBackground();
Shape.setColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Place the above code within the button `onClick`.